# How to assign object inside another object

Tags: javascript

Below is the function that does some stuff.

```
ns.Line2Point = function (params) {
        points = params.points;
        // code here
};
```

In the code above, `params object` contains a `points object`. So, when I want to call `Line2Point` method, I must create a object, and it contain points object. But, I don't know how to in Javascript. I just have some ideas like the code below, but don't know it true or false:

```
    var params;
    var points;
    // some code to initialize for points object
    params.points = points
    ns.Line2Point(params)
```

Please teach me this. Thanks :)

Comment: I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you said you just need to initialize params.

```
var params = {};   // initialize to an object literal
params.points = {}; // points is now an object literal, too
```

if you already have `points`, initialize `params`, then do

```
params.points = points; // assign points to the points property of params
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
points = [
    {
        x: 10,
        y: 25
    },
    {
        x: 20,
        y: 35
    }
]
```

Points is an array now, that consists of 2 objects, that consist of 2 variables each: `x` and `y`.

Comment: but because `Line2Point` input is `params` object, and inside method, it use : `params.points`, so , after created points (actual is an array), we must covered it in `params`. , right ? And this is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Declare params as object first.

var params = {};